# How to access C variable for inline assembly manipulation?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

Given this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int x = 1;
    printf("Hello x = %d\n", x);
}
```

I'd like to access and manipulate the variable x in inline assembly. Ideally, I want to change its value using inline assembly. GNU assembler, and using the AT&T syntax.

Comment: Which variant of inline assembly? GCC-style is the only good one, but it would be a waste of time answering if you're looking for MSVC..

Comment: Which compiler? Which processor? What did you try and in what way didn't it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In GNU C inline asm, with x86 AT&T syntax:
(But https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm if you can avoid it).

```
// this example doesn't really need volatile: the result is the same every time
asm volatile("movl $0, %[some]"
    : [some] "=r" (x)
);
```

after this, x contains 0.

Note that you should generally avoid `mov` as the first or last instruction of an asm statement.  Don't copy from `%[some]` to a hard-coded register like `%%eax`, just use `%[some]` as a register, letting the compiler do register allocation.

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info for more docs and guides.

---

Not all compilers support GNU syntax. 
For example, for MSVC you do this:

`__asm mov x, 0` and `x` will have the value of `0` after this statement.

Please specify the compiler you would want to use.

Also note, doing this will restrict your program to compile with only a specific compiler-assembler combination, and will be targeted only towards a particular architecture.

In most cases, you'll get as good or better results from using pure C and intrinsics, not inline asm.

Comment: GNU assembler, using the AT&T syntax

Comment: I look forward to your assistance. Suppose I want to give X the value of 10, how would I do that?

Comment: @user1888502 You would need to learn x86 assembly first to do that. though `movl $10 ...` would do it here

Comment: @user1888502 in my answers, replace 0 with 10 and you have it :-)

Comment: What foes the %[some] mean?

Comment: `some` in the above extended-asm is a pseudo-name, which is defined as a `r` which it is assigned(the `=` denotes PUTTING TO) `x` which is the variable name.

Comment: very interesring amswer but what about Intel syntax?

Answer (score 0):

`asm("mov $0, %1":"=r" (x):"r" (x):"cc");`
 -- this may get you on the right track. Specify register use as much as possible for performance and efficiency.  However, as Aniket points out, highly architecture dependent and requires gcc.