# manipulating c variable via inline assembly

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access c variable for inline assembly manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617953/how-to-access-c-variable-for-inline-assembly-manipulation)

Given this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int x = 1;
  printf("Hello x = %d\n", x);


  }
```

I'd like to access and manipulate the variable x in inline assembly. Ideally, I want to change its value using inline assembly. GNU assembler, and using the AT&T syntax. Suppose I want to change the value of x to 11, right after the printf statement, how would I go by doing this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info, and other relevant Q&As: [Why can't local variable be used in GNU C basic inline asm statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60227941) / [Code blocks Ver.16.01 crashing during run cycle of programme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41117655)

Answer (score 15):

The `asm()` function follows this order:

```
asm ( "assembly code"
           : output operands                  /* optional */
           : input operands                   /* optional */
           : list of clobbered registers      /* optional */
);
```

and to put 11 to x with assembly via your c code:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 1;

    asm ("movl %1, %%eax;"
         "movl %%eax, %0;"
         :"=r"(x) /* x is output operand and it's related to %0 */
         :"r"(11)  /* 11 is input operand and it's related to %1 */
         :"%eax"); /* %eax is clobbered register */

   printf("Hello x = %d\n", x);
}
```

You can simplify the above asm code by avoiding the clobbered register

```
asm ("movl %1, %0;"
    :"=r"(x) /* related to %0*/
    :"r"(11) /* related to %1*/
    :);
```

You can simplify more by avoiding the input operand and by using local constant value from asm instead from c:

```
asm ("movl $11, %0;" /* $11 is the value 11 to assign to %0 (related to x)*/
    :"=r"(x) /* %0 is related x */
    :
    :);
```

Another example: [compare 2 numbers with assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523333/compare-2-numbers-with-assembly)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info for guides, and the official docs are better than when this answer was posted: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html.  (And the neighbouring pages in the manual about generic and machine-specific constraints.)  See also https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm - avoid it when you can get the compiler to make the asm you want from C intrinsics: much less chance of mistakes (like destroying a register or memory location without telling the compiler) that create undefined behaviour.