# Code blocks Ver.16.01 crashing during run cycle of programme

Tags: c++, x86, g++, inline-assembly

I have a program which has been proved to run on an older version of codeblocks (ver 13.12) but does not seem to work when I try it on the newer version (ver 16.01). The purpose of the programme is to enter two integers which will then be added, mult etc. It uses asm code which I am new at. My question is why does it say windows has stopped responding after I type 2 integers and press enter?

Here is the code:

```
//Program 16

#include <stdio.h>
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

int main() {

int arg1, arg2, add, sub, mul, quo, rem ;

cout << "Enter two integer numbers : " ;
cin >>  arg1 >> arg2 ;
cout << endl;

  asm ( "addl %%ebx, %%eax;" : "=a" (add) : "a" (arg1) , "b" (arg2) );
  asm ( "subl %%ebx, %%eax;" : "=a" (sub) : "a" (arg1) , "b" (arg2) );
 asm ( "imull %%ebx, %%eax;" : "=a" (mul) : "a" (arg1) , "b" (arg2) );

asm ( "movl $0x0, %%edx;"
"movl %2, %%eax;"
"movl %3, %%ebx;"
"idivl %%ebx;" : "=a" (quo), "=d" (rem) : "g" (arg1), "g" (arg2) );

cout<< arg1 << "+" << arg2 << " = " << add << endl;
 cout<< arg1 << "-" << arg2 << " = " << sub << endl;
cout<< arg1 << "x" << arg2 << " = " << mul << endl;
cout<< arg1 << "/" << arg2 << " = " << quo << "  ";
 cout<< "remainder " << rem << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Wild stab: Initialize `quo` and `rem` to remove possibility of UB.

Comment: Odd. Can't reproduce if I hardcode `arg1` and `arg2` and remove the `cin`

Comment: Multiple ASM statements like this won't be guaranted to be in the order they appear. That likely won't be the issue, but will be is that the 4th ASM block doesn't list "EBX" in the clobber list (but its contents are destroyed) and `"=a"` and `"=d"` should probably be early clobbers since both of them are modified before all the inputs are consumed. You could try `"=&a"`  and `"=&d"` . I recommend looking at the generated code with the `debug`/`debug windows` `disassembly` option (as well as turn on "CPU Registers Window" the same way)

Comment: And likely it worked previously because the version you used had different optimizations or performed optimizations differently. The fact it would have worked previously would have been sheer luck. Likely the error you are getting (that crashes) is an arithmetic exception because the values of _EDX_, _EBX_ and _EAX_ had the wrong values because of the [early clobber issue](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Modifiers.html).

Comment: And of course that 4th ASM block (the one doing IDIV) could be simplified by setting up constraints differently and eliminating all the `MOVL` instructions. But one can always tweak things as you learn how to use inline assembler templates more effectively.

Comment: I see this code is nearly (not exact) identical to this code: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15971/Using-Inline-Assembly-in-C-C . If you are the author of that CodeProject project you'd probably want to look into early clobbers and register assignment and fix the code examples. If you have borrowed their code as a template you may wish to let the author know the code is flawed.

Comment: And to end my comments. Since GCC/G++ inline assembly if fraught with pitfalls, and has a steeper learning curve than many realize, one of SO's users David Wohlferd wrote an article on why you shouldn't use inline assembly unless you really need to.

Comment: And that article is here: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm (since it doesn't appear that Michael linked it).  BTW Michael, if you have any additions for that page, let me know.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd : I originally linked to it, but I copy and pasted my original comment, deleted original to fix a mistake, forgot to put the link back in. Thanks ;-)

Comment: @user4581301 : in the OPs code the assembler template only uses `quo` and `rem` as outputs. They won't need to be initialized in this case. Had they been input or input/output operands then they would have to be initialized.

Comment: @MichaelPetch that's what I would expect. I wouldn't even have suggested it except when I poked at OP's code it did stop crashing when I initialized the values, but it also stopped crashing when I swapped to hardcoded arg1 and arg2. Some other voodoo was going on, so I shut up and left it for folk with stronger assembly Gung-Fu.

Comment: @user4581301 No problem at all! GCC's Extended Inline Assembly needs to come with some big red warnings when used. It is so easy to get even the simplest things wrong and then pay for it later.

Answer (score 4):

As Michael has said, your problem probably comes from your 4th asm statement being written incorrectly.

The first thing you need to understand when writing inline asm is what registers are and how they are used.  Registers are a fundamental concept in x86 assembler programming, so if you don't know what they are, it's time for you to find an x86 assembly language primer.

Once you've got that, you need to understand that when compiler runs, it is *using* those registers in the code it generates.  For example if you do `for (int x=0; x<10; x++)`, x is (probably) going to end up in a register.  So what happens if gcc decides to use ebx to hold the value of 'x', and then your asm statement stomps on ebx, putting some other value in it?  gcc doesn't 'parse' your asm to figure out what you are doing.  The only clue it has about what your asm does are those constraints listed after the asm instructions.

That's what Michael means when he says *"the 4th ASM block doesn't list "EBX" in the clobber list (but its contents are destroyed)"*.  If we look at your asm:

```
asm ("movl $0x0, %%edx;"
     "movl %2, %%eax;"
     "movl %3, %%ebx;"
     "idivl %%ebx;" 
  : "=a" (quo), "=d" (rem) 
  : "g" (arg1), "g" (arg2));
```

You see that the 3rd line is moving a value into ebx, but there's nothing in the constraints that follow to say that it is going to be changed.  The fact that your program is crashing is probably due to gcc using that register for something else.  The simplest fix might be to "list EBX in the clobber list":

```
asm ("movl $0x0, %%edx;"
     "movl %2, %%eax;"
     "movl %3, %%ebx;"
     "idivl %%ebx;" 
  : "=a" (quo), "=d" (rem) 
  : "g" (arg1), "g" (arg2)
  : "ebx");
```

This tells gcc that ebx may be changed by the asm (aka it 'clobbers' it), and that it doesn't need to have any particular value when the asm statement begins, and won't have any particular value in it when the asm exits.

However, while that may be 'simplest,' it isn't necessarily the best.  For example instead of using the `"g"` constraint for arg2, we can use the `"b"` constraint:

```
asm ("movl $0x0, %%edx;"
     "movl %2, %%eax;"
     "idivl %%ebx;" 
  : "=a" (quo), "=d" (rem) 
  : "g" (arg1), "b" (arg2));
```

This lets us get rid of the `movl %3, %%ebx` statement, since gcc will ensure the value is in ebx before calling the asm, and we don't need to clobber it anymore.

But why use ebx?  idiv doesn't require any particular register there, and maybe gcc is already using ebx for something else.  How about letting gcc just pick some register it isn't using?  We do this using the `"r"` constraint:

```
asm ("movl $0x0, %%edx;"
     "movl %2, %%eax;"
     "idivl %3;" 
  : "=a" (quo), "=d" (rem) 
  : "g" (arg1), "r" (arg2));
```

Notice that the idiv now uses %3, which means "use the thing that is in the (zero-based) parameter #3."  In this case, that's the register that contains arg2.

However, we can still do better.  As you have already seen in your previous asm statements, you can use the `"a"` constraint to tell gcc to put a particular variable into the eax register.  Which means we can do this:

```
asm ("movl $0x0, %%edx;"
     "idivl %3;" 
  : "=a" (quo), "=d" (rem) 
  : "a" (arg1), "r" (arg2));
```

Again, 1 fewer instruction since we don't need to move the value into eax anymore.  So how about that `movl $0x0, %%edx` thing?  Well, we can get rid of that too:

```
asm ("idivl %3"
  : "=a" (quo), "=d" (rem) 
  : "a" (arg1), "r" (arg2), "d" (0));
```

This uses the `"d"` constraint to put 0 into edx before executing the asm.  That brings us to my final version:

```
asm ("idivl %3"
  : "=a" (quo), "=d" (rem) 
  : "a" (arg1), "r" (arg2), "d" (0)
  : "cc");
```

This says:

- On input, put arg1 into eax, arg2 into some register (that we'll refer to using %3), and 0 into edx.
- On output, eax will contain the quotient, edx will contain the remainder.  This is how the idiv instruction works.
- The "cc" clobber tells gcc that your asm modifies the flags registers (eflags), which idiv does as a side effect.

Now, despite having described all this, I usually think using inline asm is a bad idea.  It's cool, it's powerful, it gives interesting insight into how the gcc compiler works.  But look at all the weird things you "just have to know" in order to work with this.  And as you have noticed, if you get any of them wrong, weird things can happen.

It's true all these things are documented in gcc's docs.  The simple constraints (like `"r"` and `"g"`) are doc'ed [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html).  The specific register constraints for the x86 are in the 'x86 family' [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html).  And the detailed description of all the asm features is [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).  So if you **must** use this stuff (for example if you are supporting some existing code that uses this), the information is out there.

But there's a much shorter read [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm) that gives you a whole list of reasons *not* to use inline asm.  That's the read I'd recommend.  Stick with C, and let the compiler handle all that register junk for you.

PS While I'm at this:

```
asm ( "addl %2, %0" : "=r" (add) : "0" (arg1) , "r" (arg2) : "cc");
asm ( "subl %2, %0" : "=r" (sub) : "0" (arg1) , "r" (arg2) : "cc");
asm ( "imull %2, %0" : "=r" (mul) : "0" (arg1) , "r" (arg2) : "cc");
```

Check out the gcc [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#InputOperands) to see what it means to use a digit in an input operand.

Comment: When I first taught myself how to use GCC's inline assembler (about a year ago), I remember having one hell of a time. I read the documentation, which was pretty decent, but hard to follow for a beginner. I found various tutorials online, but most of them seemed to be of poor quality, and not being an expert, I didn't feel I was in much of a position to assess their accuracy. I wish I had come across an answer like this one, that walked me through a *simple, real world example* step-by-step. This makes initially strange concepts like clobbers and constraints so much easier to grok.

Comment: Just as an addendum since `add` and `multiply` are commutative you can give another hint to the compiler that the 2 arguments in that case can be switched around. For Add and Multiple ASM blocks you could use the [percent modifier](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Modifiers.html) `"%0"` as a constraint for arg1 which would allow it and the operand following (arg2 in both cases) it to be swapped at compiler discretion.

Comment: @CodyGray - Thanks for the compliment. When I started with inline asm (about 3 years ago) the docs were [awful](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).  That's why I re-wrote them (I'm glad you found them useful).  You are right though, they aren't a good HowTo guide.  My intent at the time was just to start by (completely) describing how the darn thing works. Ironically, now that I understand it, I spend most of my time trying to discourage people from using it! As for bad tutorials, as Michael points out, OP's code apparently comes from (an unmaintained) one.

Comment: I have edited it to your suggestions and the only solution that works completely is this:   

asm ( "addl %2, %0" : "=r" (add) : "0" (arg1) , "r" (arg2) : "cc");  
  
asm ( "subl %2, %0" : "=r" (sub) : "0" (arg1) , "r" (arg2) : "cc");

asm ( "imull %2, %0" : "=r" (mul) : "0" (arg1) , "r" (arg2) : "cc");


  asm (
        "idivl %3;"
        : "=a" (quo), "=d" (rem)
        : "a" (arg1), "r" (arg2), "d" (0)
        : "cc");

The other asm solutions in the above main answer on this thread allowed the program to run however the division expression showed up as "0 remainder 0"

Comment: @AbramsM101 : The reason the intermediate solutions don't work in the post above is because the author excluded the main factor for the failure of the code you had - the problem with early clobbers. By the time he worked to his final solution early clobbers were not a problem because he had reduced the inline assembly to a point they didn't exist anymore. The intermediate steps still are an issue.

Answer (score 4):

David Wohlferd has given a very good answer on how to better work with *GCC* extended assembly templates to do the work of your existing code.

A question may arise as to why the code presented fails with Codeblocks 16.01 w/*GCC* where as it may have worked previously. As it stands the code looks pretty simple, so what could have possibly gone wrong?

The best thing I recommend is learning to use the debugger and set break points in Codeblocks. It is very simple (but beyond the scope of this answer). You can learn more about debugging in the [Codeblocks documentation](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Debugging_with_Code::Blocks).

If you used the debugger with Codeblocks 16.01, with a stock C++ console project you may have discovered that the program is giving you an *Arithmetic Exception* on the *IDIV* instruction in the assembly template. This is what appears in my console output:

> Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.

---

These lines of code do as you would expect:

```
asm ( "addl %%ebx, %%eax;" : "=a" (add) : "a" (arg1) , "b" (arg2) );
asm ( "subl %%ebx, %%eax;" : "=a" (sub) : "a" (arg1) , "b" (arg2) );
asm ( "imull %%ebx, %%eax;" : "=a" (mul) : "a" (arg1) , "b" (arg2) );
```

This is where was have issues:

```
asm ( "movl $0x0, %%edx;"
      "movl %2, %%eax;"
      "movl %3, %%ebx;"
      "idivl %%ebx;" : "=a" (quo), "=d" (rem) : "g" (arg1), "g" (arg2) );
```

One thing Codeblocks can do for you is show you the assembly code it generated. Pull down the `Debug` menu, select `Debugging Windows >` and `Disassembly`. The `Watches` and `CPU Registers` windows I highly recommend as well.

If you review the generated code with CodeBlocks 16.01 w/GCC you might discover it produced this:

```
/* Automatically produced by the assembly template for input constraints */
mov    -0x20(%ebp),%eax      /* EAX = value of arg1 */
mov    -0x24(%ebp),%edx      /* EDX = value of arg2 */

/* Our assembly template instructions */
mov    $0x0,%edx             /* EDX = 0 - we just clobbered the previous EDX! */
mov    %eax,%eax             /* EAX remains the same */
mov    %edx,%ebx             /* EBX = EDX = 0. */
idiv   %ebx                  /* EBX is 0 so this is division by zero!! *

/* Automatically produced by the assembly template for output constraints */
mov    %eax,-0x18(%ebp)      /* Value at quo = EAX */
mov    %edx,-0x1c(%ebp)      /* Value at rem = EDX */
```

I have commented the code and it should be obvious why this code won't work. We effectively ended up placing zero in *EBX* and then attempted to use that as a divisor with *IDIV* and that produced an arithmetic exception (division by zero in this case).

This happened because *GCC* will (by default) assume that all the input operands are used (consumed) BEFORE the output operands are written to. We never told *GCC* that it couldn't potentially use the same input operands as output operands. *GCC* considers this situation an [*Early Clobber*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Modifiers.html). It provides a mechanism to mark an output constraint as early clobber using `&` (ampersand) modifier:

> `&'
>
> Means (in a particular alternative) that this operand is an earlyclobber operand, which is modified before the instruction is finished using the input operands. Therefore, this operand may not lie in a register that is used as an input operand or as part of any memory address.

By changing the operands so that the early clobbers are dealt with, we can place `&` on both the output constraints like this:

```
"idivl %%ebx;" : "=&a" (quo), "=&d" (rem) : "g" (arg1), "g" (arg2) );
```

In this case `arg1` and `arg2` will not be passed in through any of the operands marked with `&`. This means this code will avoid using *EAX* and *EDX* for the input operands `arg1` and `arg2`.

The other issue is that *EBX* is modified by your code but you don't tell *GCC*. You could simply add *EBX* to the clobber list in the assembly template like this:

```
"idivl %%ebx;" : "=&a" (quo), "=&d" (rem) : "g" (arg1), "g" (arg2) : "ebx");
```

So this code should work, but is not efficient:

```
asm ( "movl $0x0, %%edx;"
      "movl %2, %%eax;"
      "movl %3, %%ebx;"
      "idivl %%ebx;" : "=&a" (quo), "=&d" (rem) : "g" (arg1), "g" (arg2) : "ebx");
```

The generated code will now look something like:

```
/* Automatically produced by the assembler template for input constraints */
mov    -0x30(%ebp),%ecx      /* ECX = value of arg1 */
mov    -0x34(%ebp),%esi      /* ESI = value of arg2 */

/* Our assembly template instructions */
mov    $0x0,%edx             /* EDX = 0 */
mov    %ecx,%eax             /* EAX = ECX = arg1 */
mov    %esi,%ebx             /* EBX = ESI = arg2 */
idiv   %ebx

/* Automatically produced by the assembler template for output constraints */
mov    %eax,-0x28(%ebp)      /* Value at quo = EAX */
mov    %edx,-0x2c(%ebp)      /* Value at rem = EDX */
```

This time the input operands for `arg1` and `arg2` didn't share the same registers that would conflict with the `MOV` instructions inside our inline assembly template.

---

### Why other (including older) versions of GCC work?

If *GCC* had generated instructions using registers other than *EAX*, *EDX*, and *EBX* for `arg1` and `arg2` operands then it would have worked. But the fact it may have worked was just by luck. To see what happend with older Codeblocks and the *GCC* that came with it, I'd recommend reviewing the code generated in that environment the same way I have discussed above.

Early clobbering, and register clobbering in general is a reason that extended assembler templates can be tricky, and a reason extended assembler templates should be used sparingly especially if you don't have a solid understanding.

You can create code that appears to work, but is coded incorrectly. A different version of *GCC* or even different optimization levels may alter the behaviour of the code. Sometimes these bugs can be so subtle that as a program grows the bug manifests itself in other ways that may be hard to trace.

Another rule of thumb is that not all code you find on the internet is bug free, and the subtle complexities of extended inline assembly is often overlooked in tutorials. I discovered the code you used seems to be based on this [Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15971/Using-Inline-Assembly-in-C-C). Unfortunately the author didn't have a thorough understanding of the intracies involved. The code may have worked at the time, but not necessarily now.