# Smallest 32-bit Bit Reversal in C using inline __asm()

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86-64

Trying to create the smallest 32-bit Bit Reversal in C using inline `__asm()`.

So far, I've managed to get the `__asm()` code size to `23` bytes.

I'm curious if there are ways to further decrease the code size by using

- compiler instrinsics
- specialized assembly instructions
- vanilla C code

**Example**

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5Ef5s6Kdr)

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int CodeSize;


void print_binary(unsigned int number) { if (number >> 1) print_binary(number >> 1); putc((number & 1) ? '1' : '0', stdout); }


void reverseBits(unsigned int OriginalValue)
{
    unsigned int ReversedValue = 0;

    start_asm:
    __asm__ (
        "movl  %1, %%eax\n"       // load the value
        "xorl  %%ebx, %%ebx\n"    // clear EBX (optimized)
        "bsrl  %%eax, %%ecx\n"    // find highest order bit set to 1 in EAX
        "incl  %%ecx\n"           // increment to get the correct number of iterations
    "reverse:\n\t"                // local label
        "shrl  $1, %%eax\n"       // shift the LSB of EAX to the carry flag CF
        "rcll  $1, %%ebx\n"       // the MSB of EBX goes into CF and CF's previous value goes into the LSB of EBX
        "loop  reverse\n"         // loop back to the local label
        "movl  %%ebx, %0"         // move the result to the output
        : "=r" (ReversedValue)    // output
        : "r" (OriginalValue)     // input
        : "eax", "ebx", "ecx"     // clobbered registers
    );
    end_asm:

    CodeSize = (char *)&&end_asm - (char *)&&start_asm;

    printf("\nOriginal: 0x%X ", OriginalValue); print_binary(OriginalValue);
    printf("\nReversed: 0x%X ", ReversedValue); print_binary(ReversedValue);
    printf("\n");
}


int main()
{
    reverseBits(0xfeedface);  
    reverseBits(0xfeed);  
    reverseBits(0xfe);               

    printf("\nCodeSize: %u bytes\n", CodeSize); 
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Original: 0xFEEDFACE 11111110111011011111101011001110
Reversed: 0x735FB77F 1110011010111111011011101111111

Original: 0xFEEDFA 111111101110110111111010
Reversed: 0x5FB77F 10111111011011101111111

Original: 0xFEED 1111111011101101
Reversed: 0xB77F 1011011101111111

Original: 0xFE 11111110
Reversed: 0x7F 1111111

CodeSize: 23 bytes
```

**Update**

From the helpful comments below, the code size is now [13 bytes](https://godbolt.org/z/obW98M87E)

```
uint32_t reverseBits(uint32_t OriginalValue) {
    uint32_t ReversedValue = 0;

    __asm__ (
        "start_asm:\n"             // start label
        "xorl  %%ebx, %%ebx\n"     // clear EBX
        "bsrl  %1, %%ecx\n"        // find highest order bit set to 1 in EAX (which is %1)
    "reverse:\n"                   // local label for looping
        "shrl  $1, %1\n"           // shift the LSB of EAX (which is %1) to the carry flag CF
        "rcll  $1, %%ebx\n"        // the MSB of EBX goes into CF and CF's previous value goes into the LSB of EBX
        "decl  %%ecx\n"            // manually decrement ECX
        "jns   reverse\n"          // jump to reverse if sign flag is set (i.e., if ecx is negative)
        "end_asm:\n"               // end label
        : "=b" (ReversedValue)     // output directly to EBX
        : "a" (OriginalValue)      // input directly to EAX
        : "ecx"                    // clobbered register
    );

    return ReversedValue;
}
```

Comment: Since you specified input and output in registers it makes little sense to hardcode `eax` and `ebx`. Just use those registers instead. Also if you are optimizing for size, you can loop a fixed 32 times

Comment: This may be better suited for https://codegolf.stackexchange.com.  Incidentally, [such a challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/36213/134) already exists there.  You can do it [in 12 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36303/134).

Comment: Though I see that you wish to only reverse as many bits as the number is large.  Try this (input in `ecx`, output in `eax`): `xor %eax, %eax; 0: rcl %eax; shr %ecx; jbe 0b`.  8 bytes in total.

Comment: @vengy Your code uses `ebx` which does not appear in the original.  I am not sure what this is supposed to achieve.  Just try `out = 0; asm ( "0: rcl %0; shr %1; jbe 0b" : "=r"(out), "+&r"(in));`

Comment: @vengy No need, I'll request migration.

Comment: Your `start_asm` and `end_asm` labels aren't inside the `asm()` statement!  The "code size" they measure includes instructions like `movl    -36(%rbp), %edx; movl  %edx, %eax` to set up the `"r"` input for the asm statement (extra inefficient because you're looking at an anti-optimized `-O0` build), and more to store the result after. https://godbolt.org/z/3ochc4bWr - note the use of `.L7` and `.L6`.  If you put labels inside the asm template, and declare them as `extern char start_asm[], end_asm[]` at global scope, then you can subtract them and measure just your own asm instructions.

Comment: Also, a bit-reversing function should return the result, not print it.  Write a separate wrapper that prints the input and output after calling it.

Comment: @Peter Cordes. Nice, based on your suggestions, it's now 17 bytes! [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ea49c4jPT) Thanks.

Comment: That's still wasting 4 bytes on `mov %1, %%eax` and `movl  %%ebx, %0` like Jester mentioned, vs. asking for the input in a `"+r"` operand so you can modify it, and output with an `"=&r"` early-clobber output operand so it's safe to write that operand before you read the input.  Then you'd just use `%1` and `%0` in your asm template like fuz showed, or give them names.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info and [Code blocks Ver.16.01 crashing during run cycle of programme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41117655) re: using the right constraints.

Comment: Added [tag:x86-64] since that appears to be the only architecture you are interested in.  Please always use an architecture tag for assembly questions.  The answer could be very different for other architectures, e.g. ARMv8 simply has an `rbit` instruction.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Older ARM also have `rbit`; apparently it was new in ARMv6T2 (https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0489/c/arm-and-thumb-instructions/general-data-processing-instructions/rev--rev16--revsh--and-rbit) so it exists in Cortex-M where code-size optimization would be more relevant.  (Although of course it's also a huge win for speed.)  But yes, ARMv8 provides it in AArch64 state, too.

Comment: @vengy: If you want to minimize machine-code size using inline asm, don't make it a `naked` function; let the compiler inline it so you don't need a `ret`.  A `naked` function is defeating the purpose of inline `asm()`; it's basically equivalent to writing a separate `.s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[10 bytes:](https://godbolt.org/z/bYh7fzvYK)

```
__asm__ (
    "start_asm:\n"
    "xorl  %%ebx, %%ebx\n"    //Clear destination and CF
 "repeat:\n\t"
    "rcll  $1, %%ebx\n"       // Shift CF into destination LSB
    "shrl  $1, %%eax\n"       // Shift LSB from source into CF
    "jnz  repeat\n"           // If source is not zero - repeat
                              // else (source is zero, CF is always 1)
    "rcll  $1, %%ebx\n"       // Shift the last 1 into destination
    "end_asm:\n"
    : "=b" (ReversedValue)    // output
    : "a" (OriginalValue)     // input
    :                         // no clobbered registers
);
```

Comment: Nice! So the last instruction that affects ZF is `shrl $1, %%eax`. The `jnz` checks if EAX has become zero after the shift operation. If it's zero, all the bits from the original number have been processed, and we can move on. If it's non-zero, there are still bits left to reverse, so we keep looping. The final instruction `rcll  $1, %%ebx` processes the last bit still in the carry flag (CF) to ensure that the final bit from EAX is shifted into EBX. Very clever! :)

Comment: I generally prefer `adc reg, reg` to `rcl reg, 1`, but it does not matter for code size here (+1)

Answer (score 1):

[6 bytes](https://godbolt.org/z/Ezje1E3rM)

```
uint32_t reverseBits(uint32_t OriginalValue) {
    uint32_t ReversedValue = 0;

    __asm__ (
    "repeat:\n\t"
        "shrl  $1, %%eax\n"        // Shift LSB from source into CF
        "rcll  $1, %%ebx\n"        // Shift CF into destination LSB
        "jnz   repeat\n"           // If source EAX is not zero - repeat
        : "=b" (ReversedValue)     // output: EBX
        : "a"  (OriginalValue),    // input: OriginalValue is loaded into EAX.
          "b"  (ReversedValue)     // input: ReversedValue (0) is loaded into EBX. 
        :                          // no clobbered registers
    );    

    return ReversedValue;
}
```

Comment: Oh, RCL does not affect ZF. Didn't know that.

Comment: I was surprised too that [RCL](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_273.html) does not affect the SF, ZF, AF, and PF flags. Credit really goes to your ideas. Thanks!