# Inline assembly statements in C code and extended ASM for ARM Cortex architectures

Tags: c, assembly, arm, inline-assembly, keil

I am trying to compile the following two pieces of code with **ARM Compiler 5** for a Cortex A microprocessor:

**Part 1**:

```
static inline void cp15_write_sctlr(uint32_t value)
{
    asm("mcr p15, 0, %0, c1, c0, 0" :: "r"(value));
}

static inline uint32_t cp15_read_actlr(void)
{
    uint32_t actlr;
    asm("mrc p15, 0, %0, c1, c0, 1" : "=r"(actlr));
    return actlr;
}
```

**Part 2**:

```
static inline void dmb(void)
{
    asm("dmb" ::: "memory");
}

static inline void dsb(void)
{
    asm("dsb" ::: "memory");
}

static inline void isb(void)
{
    asm("isb" ::: "memory");
}
```

In both cases I get compile errors. See below, as an example.

```
line 64: Error:  #18: expected a ")"
    asm("dsb" ::: "memory");
```

Are the error caused by the compiler version (ARM compiler 5), which does not support Extended Asm?

If I re-write the code in **Part 1** as follows, I do not get any error. Is the following code equivalent to that in Part 1?

```
static inline void cp15_write_sctlr(uint32_t value)
{
    __asm
    {
        MCR p15, 0, value, c1, c0, 0
    }
}

static inline uint32_t cp15_read_actlr(void)
{
    uint32_t actlr;
    __asm
    {
        MRC p15, 0, actlr, c1, c0, 1
    }
    return actlr;
}
```

How could I rewrite the code in Part 2, if the compiler does not support extended Asm?
I have in mind the following, but I am not sure it is the same.

```
static inline void dmb(void)
{
    __schedule_barrier();
    __asm("dmb");
    __schedule_barrier();
}

static inline void dsb(void)
{
    __schedule_barrier();
    __asm("dsb");
    __schedule_barrier();
}

static inline void isb(void)
{
    __schedule_barrier();
    __asm("isb");
    __schedule_barrier();
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What, _specifically_ is your error? Please _edit_ your question, and post the _exact_ error text in a separate code block. What compiler are you using (e.g. `gcc`)? And, what assembler? The compiler may support `__asm` and/or `__asm__` but _not_ `asm` [they have the same capabilities].

Comment: @CraigEstey Post edited. Compiler is Arm Compiler version 5, as I wrote in the post. Thanks.

Comment: When I've done [commercial] arm development, I've used the `gcc` cross-compiler under Ubuntu. I'd never heard of "arm compiler 5" before. I looked it up, and [AFAICT] it's a rebranded Keil suite [that you have to pay for]. Keil has been known to lag a bit on some things. You _could_ isolate the asm stuff into a separate file and compile that with `gcc` and load the `.o` into the IDE. From: https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124246903.htm it appears to _not_ have extended asm.

Comment: Or, if you isolate the asm code, you could put it into functions defined in a `.s` file. I suspect performance would be okay [albeit, not as fast as pure inline]. You can achieve the same with a C function that is 100% the asm block and is pure. It might still work as a `static inline` function. I'd disassemble the `.o` file to see the actual code generated for a given function to see how well it works.

Answer (score 0):

> Are the error caused by the compiler version (ARM compiler 5), which does not support Extended Asm?

That's GNU C inline Extend Asm syntax, so yes obviously a compiler that doesn't support it will error.

---

[A GCC change in 2016](https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-patches/2016-05/msg00419.html) ([PR24414](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24414#c20)) gave non-empty Basic Asm statements an implicit `"memory"` clobber, as well as making them implicitly clobber `"cc"` on targets like x86 where Extended asm does that.  So if your GCC version is new enough, you I guess *could* be able to safely use Basic Asm here, assuming that undocumented GCC behaviour continues to be present in future GCC versions to help badly written or old code work the way it was probably intended.  (Assuming that's actually also safe in Keil, with an implicit memory barrier there, too).  I don't know what GCC versions this made it into

(A litmus test for storing and reloading a global across an asm statement will tell you how this behaves on any given GCC version.  If you see the register value being reused for `asm("" ::: );`  (Extended with explicitly no memory clobber) but not for `asm("# comment");` (non-empty Basic), that implies non-empty Basic asm statements have an implicit memory clobber.  Otherwise you'd expect the same optimization as with Extended.  This [Godbolt compiler explorer link](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tQVvQAZPLUwA5YwCNMxEJNIAHVAsLraewyaCnt5qdFY29kZOLm5KKqG0DATMxAT%2BxqacisqYqr5JKQThdo7OrorJqemBWQqVRdYlUWWSAJSKqAbEyBwA5AD0/QDUDJiYQwgEBO4KIIPAyMgAdMC0BkskwP0OBsAAXniswv0KCKgA7gD6O8BLyMB44gDMAGJ46M8AIpLc3DxST2QkgADOJgQBBMHg6wEIbeWgAa2esghUJhQwczG8yEumCM7gIAE8IK0huIAOwo8FDGlDdEEfFkp6fOHWJFPKm0oZYowQKSSfmtZFc2mDIZ4gmEkBDWioIZGPFDZCsVAOaKkOHMBXchQ63n8/kgI2tJY02xy4jKVDMD4QrmWghdWhDBnuMkyVmI5FQimfH0Q9GY7GXWU2fFEklkylQrn0xlfT3szm0nl8yQCyRPJWoIwK%2BiC4Wi4ahgC0EqJGoUWvGWL1aYzkiNIH5CqMJEJBbttIdTpd8Y98KTPvJftRAfo4oAHgRzJh0JdW8rVdFIxTkzS426E4PvV2aamDZns7mtARDUaW3j2wWOTSxXh8aw8MhCKxCUMAG76ZhqdjS2VDJ00wGAQCgxt2mCOsQzquu60iJrukIjv60ITpg06zvOsqLiqarOKu0Z7nSE6wdubKIVyB7pgCx55me6ZNkKt5DGK2AYdoc56tK6HuE%2BL4EG%2BQzoHQYC9LCS54cQ8p4uBNI9tBfZbgO5EcsOo7gr07SsCAvQAKy9KQpi9MCBmoDpOhyHIcKdN04wApwBkEDpJmtO0CIgH8SxPMCuncAAHN5kh%2BeSIIAGxuNpvTcAZRhcMCwJLPFSXJclTyGc5pk6QZszAqQTnGZppBwLAMBQKVEBIGg%2BKHM45CUFV7g1S4wChbwVCHDOxCzBADgZaQDjWCkUq9A5pBVXRADytBvn1WBGCIwB/gVpD4JaeQfpgszLehuQgX0o0wsofVPg4xBDXoWA6aNBDEA%2BV2FTQ9BMGwHA8PwgjCKIKCWTIQh4A4syQO0qAEr4W0lhNTzZTkeQaBA5jVJkpDmMUkTREEXg%2BHQiMYyEvio6ULi1DDCQFFU%2BgZIIcS5KT9QE80RMVIUOO1HTjRo2UnDtAoNk9FwWk6fp6XLWZvSTn5oUlq1QwLMgQyhUs3BDBAuCECQ7pPFkQx6NV7BSfZpIWTIciORlrmkAgmA2mUJKkO5um5ZF0WkLF5IJU8fm6aF5LcAAnJrnCSL73DksLJmkKL2UgLl%2BUuUV5WVTmjV63VEANU1IDAOSWTtawnXdb1y0DbQQ33WNOaTdNw3h3NC1LTXeBrWoG1beHO3IHtZeHZF4cnWdxCEhd%2B2ObdsUjQ9dCMCwf5vQIEULd9xu/SdgO2yDCTg5D0PxL4mjaDjmbI9o9Po77HiYwkB9pcEWO0CfZRn9TsOJPUV/ZDvdBkw0ESEyAj%2BvxTQIh86iFHvi4X23NeavQFnpAyRlw6i3FpLaWsshjkiWJwZWqsiD60zFrHWydnAazaNrH60hTYFXNpba2Lhbb20djpZ28DMq9CjjHM2MDJAxRAG7LyntvZ%2BwDkHEOYcWEULjsVRAIAgLuBAqndOeszD4BwYIR6U8XpcF4OcM67h7owKFswiOOl7JDHOIQBAQwkFSyVqghWztY6aXaNQrAtCYHO1ikHJYoUeBPEkA7UKflgo%2BR%2BKIoxrDFDRzyhwu2IBdJ%2BS8cHXSnBQq%2B2zpIck/s/JCB0lDUJkcomUM4XAvq%2BSHHmw2l1Xe3AgA%3D%3D%3D) shows GCC 6.4 does *not* have an implicit mem clobber for Basic asm, but GCC7.1 does.

Or better, you could **use CPP macros to `#if` detect the bad compiler and omit the `::: "memory"` part that it chokes on**, on the assumption that it treats the asm statement as having a memory clobber.  Or detect `__GNUC__` and `__GNUC_MINOR__` version, etc. and use that to detect any compiler that claims compatibility with a version of the GNU dialect of C that supports Extended asm.

---

**Basic Asm should never be used inside functions in GNU C**, even for instructions like `dsb` that don't read or write registers, because there's no documented guarantee of ordering wrt. compiler-generated memory accesses.  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ConvertBasicAsmToExtended.  Normally you should only ever use it for the body of a `__attribute__((naked))` function, or at global scope.

There's no upside to Basic asm; inline asm is something you should never ever use casually, and there's nothing you can do with Basic you can't do explicitly with Extended inside a non-naked function.  (And almost nothing you actually can do safely with Basic at all: you can't safely touch registers or even global vars in memory (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60227941/why-cant-local-variable-be-used-in-gnu-c-basic-inline-asm-statements/60229384#60229384), and it's not guaranteed to be ordered wrt. anything.)

So it sucks a lot to depend on undocumented Basic Asm behaviour of having an implicit `"memory"` clobber.  There was no good reason for that implicit mem clobber GCC change (except for maybe making old and/or bad code more likely to happen to work right); Extended asm to make that explicit is always better in GNU C.

---

Does Keil support `stdatomic.h` for `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_seq_cst)` to emit a "dmb" that can't be reordered with surrounding code?  (Doesn't help for dsb and isb, though).

Comment: I need to check about the possibility to use `stdatomic.h`. I see however there are intrinsic to manage memory barriers at copile time: [link](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0472/m/compiler-features/compiler-intrinsics-for-inserting-optimization-barriers). Just wondering if `__dmb(15)`, `__dsb(15)` and `__dmb(15)` will behave as the definitions in Part 2.

Comment: @UmbertoD.: Yes, I'd assume the intrinsics prevent reordering wrt. memory accesses.  Otherwise they'd be basically unusable unless you manually barrier around them, and nobody wants that.

Comment: You can use my litmus test code from Godbolt with your Keil compiler around a `__dmb(15)` or whatever to see if it actually forces memory accesses before and after.  (Although it wouldn't actually need to block that optimization for correctness if it still forces the store to happen before the barrier.  GCC "forgetting about" the values of all global vars is an implementation detail.  But if it happens, you can be pretty sure that there's an implicit compiler memory barrier tied to the intrinsic.)