# Assembly In ARM Expected ")"

Tags: c, arm, inline-assembly, rtos

I am trying to run some assembly in C. But I keep getting this error. I am not sure why. I know it is not good practice to mix assembly and C but I am new and would like to convert all of the C to assembly if possible. I don't think I need the attribute but I was trying to do things to remedy this error. The error comes from this line:

```
__asm("   LDR r1, %[OS_curr] \n"
::"r" (OS_curr)
);
```

I am running this on a MSP432 microcontroller ARM compiler.
Thank you.

```
void PendSV_Handler() __attribute__((naked));
void PendSV_Handler(void)

{
OSThread *volatile OS_currcopy;
OS_currcopy = OS_curr;
void *sp;
__disable_interrupt();
__asm("   LDR r1, %[OS_curr] \n"
        ::"r" (OS_curr)
   );
if(OS_curr != (OSThread *) 0){
    asm("   PUSH {r4-r11}");
    OS_curr -> sp = sp;
}
sp = OS_next -> sp;
OS_curr = OS_next;

asm("   POP {r4-r11}");
__enable_interrupt();
}
```

---

```
.global         OS_curr
.global         OS_next
.global         PendSV_HandlerAsm

.curradd: .word OS_curr
.currnext: .word OS_next

PendSV_HandlerAsm:
CPSID      i

;if(OS_curr != (OSThread *)0)
LDR        r1, .curradd
LDR        r1, [r0]
CBZ        r1, PendSV_restore

;Push r4  - r11
PUSH {r4-r11}

LDR        r1, .curradd
LDR        r1, [r1]

;OS_curr -> sp = sp;
STR        sp, [r1]

PendSV_restore:

;sp=OS_next -> sp;
LDR        r1, .currnext
LDR        r1, [r0]
LDR        r1, [r0]
STR        sp, [r13]

;OS_curr = OS_next;
LDR        r1, .currnext
LDR        r1, [r1]
LDR        r2, .curradd
LDR        r1, [r1]

;Pop  r4-r11
POP        {r4-r11}

;__enable_interrupts();
CPSIE      i

;return to next thread
BX         r14
```

Comment: `## Heading ##{`?

Comment: @klutt likely misclick in SO editor :D

Comment: Are you sure `__asm` is proper syntax and not `__asm__` as is standard for GCC? or if this is *not* GCC then you cannot use GCC extended assembler...

Comment: It was the editor my bad. And I am using an ARM Compiler. I am a bit iffy if this is GCC or not. I tried __asm__,  __asm,  and asm and I get the same error for each one.

Comment: If your question has mistakes, [edit] to fix them.  First of all, even if this is GNU C, Extended Asm is not supported in `naked` functions.  Also, I think I've seen people say Keil ARMCC doesn't support GNU C extended asm.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Apparently GCC accepts `__asm()` these days.  IDK why; maybe it's helpful to accept `__asm("stuff")` as GNU C basic asm, even though that might have different semantics and requirements than it does in other compilers?  Seems more likely to just create problems; you pretty much only ever want Basic Asm in a naked function. But yeah, Keil or other commercial ARM compiler [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65460597/inline-assembly-statements-in-c-code-and-extended-asm-for-arm-cortex-architectur/65462892#comment115733758_65460597) doesn't do GNU C Extended inline asm.

Comment: So how would I go about fixing this? Is it not possible?

Comment: Write it all in assembly. Or don't use extended assembly there.

Comment: If I right it in assembly, how do I include the c variable OS_curr? I tried doing .extern OS_curr,     extern OS_curr but I get illegal mnemonic specified. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Assembler can include both code and data.  With the Gnu assembler, you can use [`.extern`](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gas-2.9.1/html_chapter/as_7.html#SEC89), but it is not needed as that is the default.  The main issue is that global 'C' variables may be adorned with an underscore.  In C++ they are mangled; they have a postfix for parameter types.  Your handler `_PendSVHandler` can be written is assembler and declared as `extern` in 'C'.  You need to conform to the ABI.  For ARM, only use registers R0-R3 or else save above R4-R10 (depending).  You could refine your question.

Comment: How would I go about this? I tried .extern OS_curr at the top of the file and it still says illegal mnemonic specified. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I added the assembly file above incase that helps.

Comment: If I make the PendSVHandler completely in C, will it be called normally as it is in C?

Comment: Your updated assembler looks good.  You need to add `.global PendSVHandler` and then you need a prototype for 'C', like `extern void PendSVHandler(void);` so that it is listed in the assembler object as something 'C' can link to.  **good** as in it will build an be called.  I don't know if it is functionally correct.

Comment: I was able to get the assembly running from C. But the issue I am having now is using the global variable in the assembly file. I updated the assembly file above. I know this isn't the best way to get answers but I don't want to have to submit a new question and go through everything again. I thought redeclaring the global variable as another variable would work but that failed.