# The code after conversion does not execute a given action

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc, inline-assembly

I was given a task to convert a certain code from C++ to ASM based on AT&T syntax, so I started with simple examples and encountered the first problem.

code from which I started the exercise

```cpp
void func() {
  int num = 1;
  std::cout << "before: " << num << std::endl;
  num = num << 3;
  std::cout << "after: " << num << std::endl;
}
```

which gives a result:

```
before: 1
after: 8
```

my translation
variable num is first local variable so it should be in address -4(%ebp)

```cpp
void func() {
  int num = 1;
  std::cout << "before: " << num << std::endl;
  asm (
    "mov -4(%ebp), %eax         \n"
    "sall $3, %eax              \n"
    "mov %eax, -4(%ebp)         \n"
  );
  std::cout << "after: " << num << std::endl;
}
```

which gives a result:

```
before: 1
after: 1
```

why this code has no effect on num var ?

Comment: I've rolled-back your edit. You should not edit a second question into an existing question, especially if the first question already has (correct) answers. If you have a new problem, open a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are writing is very implementation specific. In your case the code likely doesn't work because you are using `ebp` which is a 32-bit addressing register, while you are running on a 64-bit machine, which uses `rbp`.

**HOWEVER** you are approaching this incorrectly. Either you write pure assembly, or you use the correct (extended) C inline assembly, that correctly interfaces with local variables. Else the code will break as soon as you change something, as you have experienced yourself.

[according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14629344) the inline asm should look like:

```cpp
asm ( "assembly code"
    : output operands                  /* optional */
    : input operands                   /* optional */
    : list of clobbered registers      /* optional */
);
```

so your code could look like

```cpp
asm (
    "mov %0, %%eax;"
    "sal $3, %%eax;"
    "mov %%eax, %1;"
    :"=r" (num)
    :"r" (num)
    :"%eax"
);
```

However, you don't need to specify and use `eax`, thus the code could be simplified (and clarified) to

```cpp
asm (
    "sal $3, %[num];"
    :[num] "+r" (num)
);
```

Comment: The conversion of ebp to rbp helped me solve my first problem thank you.

Comment: This might happen to work given the surrounding code that the OP's compiler happened to generate, but is *completely* unsafe.  Modifying registers without telling the compiler about it is effectively undefined behaviour.  Never use GNU C Basic asm (no out / in / clobber constraints) inside a non-naked function, only at global scope.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ConvertBasicAsmToExtended.  This is bad answer because it endorses using inline asm completely wrong, without even mentioning the fundamental flaw in how the OP is trying to do this.  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info

Comment: That's why this breaks when the surrounding code changes.  (Or even if you compile with optimization enabled.)  It depends on massively amounts of assumptions in GCC's code-gen, including debug-mode everything-is-volatile and that registers are "dead" between statements.  And about where GCC put the variable on the stack.

Comment: @PeterCordes ok, better like this? (I'm also learning here)

Comment: Better; your first version is safe but uses EAX for no reason after forcing the compiler to give you the value in a reg (instead of its choice of reg/mem/immediate with "g"). Your final version fails to read from %1, instead blindly assuming that the compiler will pick the same register for %1 as for %0, even though you gave if the choice of any register with `"r"`.  To force the same reg, use `"0"` (where 0 is the operand-number to match).  Or more simply, just use a single read-write operand (which behind the scenes invents a matching input constraint).  `asm("sal $3, %0" : "+r"(num));`

Comment: The compiler might choose to use your asm statement as a copy-and-operate and pick different regs e.g. if it was a function body with a register arg in EDI and wanting the return value in EAX.  Or if it still wanted a copy of the old value, e.g. because of `int foo = num` before the asm statement.  So it would be easy to construct a case where that breaks, once you know what weak spot to poke at.

Comment: Timothy's edit made me look again at the middle code block.  In that case (if you're going to force 2 `mov` instructions instead of `sal $3, %0` like the syntax is designed for), you *should* be using 2 separate input and output operands, letting the compiler use the asm statement as a copy-and-shift.  Generally only force in-place if that saves instructions.  But there's no reason to write it with 2 `mov` instructions inside the asm template; let the compiler emit one mov if necessary to preserve the input.  So just showing that as a non-optimized baby-step from orig to good is ok.

Comment: @peter should I then also use %0 and %1 or does %0 alone work?

Comment: You should of course use `%0` when you mean that operand and `%1` when you mean the other operand.  Unless you force the compiler to pick the same register for both `"=r"` output and `"r"` input, they *can* be different.  My entire point was to *let* them be difference if the compiler chooses.  It can of course choose to make them the same register (if you don't use an `"=&r"` early-clobber output, which you shouldn't because you read all the inputs for the last time before writing that output for the first time.)  And often will, especially in debug builds; testing doesn't prove correctness.